# How to Insert (save) data into two table using one form in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

i have two table in DB named users and demos.
users fields has (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `phone`)
and demos fields has (`id`, `user_id`[forign key], `sex`, `city`)

Comment: use the concept of hasOne Or hasMany

Comment: show us what did u try ?

Comment: Use hasOne realtionship with savAll function in cakephp

Comment: Why r u doing this silly thing? All this fields are belongs to one table. You can't normalize this two tables. (It should be one table)

Comment: if you define user hasMany demo and demo belongs to user, be default this will work fine right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your form (your view), you must have your data ready. Make sure that every input has the following format

```
$this->Format->input('Model.field', array(...));
```

That way you can specify to which model belongs every input.

Now you have two options

**If your models have ANY relationship between**

Then you can use `saveAll()` or `saveAsociated()` methods, just make sure your data has the propper format, for example:

```
$data = array(
    'Article' => array('title' => 'My first article'),
    'Comment' => array(
        array('body' => 'Comment 1', 'user_id' => 1),
        array('body' => 'Comment 2', 'user_id' => 12),
        array('body' => 'Comment 3', 'user_id' => 40),
    ),
);
```

In that case you can do a saveAll() or saveAssociated() (for simplicity I would recommend saveAll())

**If your models DOESN'T have relationship between**

then in your controller you have to import the outer model, like this

```
$this->loadModel('ImportedModel');
```

After that you save your current model, and then create and save the outer model.

```
$this->Model->save($this->request->data);
$this->ImportedModel->save($this->request->data);
```